# Why is JFormattedTextField restoring previous value?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I am using a JFormattedTextField, when i try to delete the value in the field, it automatically restores the previous value.
What is the reason for this behaviour and how can i stop it restoring the value?

This is the code for JFormattedtextField.

```
jFormattedTextField2 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField(new DecimalFormat("###,###.##"));
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: When exactly does it restore the previous value? When you tab away from it (or change focus in some other way)?

Comment: When the focus goes away(Cursor disappears), it changes.

Comment: I hate the default behaviour. Very bug prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) allows configuring what action should be taken when focus is lost using the `setFocusLostBehavior` method.

These are the actions.

> Description
>
> `JFormattedTextField.REVERT` - Revert the display to match that of getValue, possibly losing the current edit.
>
> `JFormattedTextField.COMMIT` - Commits the current value. If the value being edited isn't considered a legal value by the AbstractFormatter
>   that is, a ParseException is thrown, then the value will not change,
>   and then edited value will persist.
>
> `JFormattedTextField.COMMIT_OR_REVERT` - Similar to COMMIT, but if the value isn't legal, behave like REVERT.
>
> `JFormattedTextField.PERSIST` - Do nothing, don't obtain a new AbstractFormatter, and don't update the value.

**** The default is `JFormattedTextField.COMMIT_OR_REVERT` so when you enter an invalid value, it's reverted and you get the previous
 consistent state**